# Why does ctx.lineWidth > 1 make batched line drawing slow?

Tags: javascript, canvas

When drawing many lines, it seemed like it would be a performance win to do them all at once on one path:

```
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    ctx.moveTo(line[0], line[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(line[2], line[3]);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
```

My initial tests showed that this was the case. For drawing many short lines, I saw ~70% speed up.

However, when I set a lineWidth value greater than 1, (either before `ctx.beginPath()`, immediately after it, or immediately before the `ctx.stroke()`) it takes two orders of magnitude longer to do the same drawing.

To demonstrate the issue, I put together a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V3puL/7/ (Warning: this might take more than a minute to finish running!)

I've tried this on a few of the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox with the same general result.

Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you draw a line of thickness of one pixel the implementer can use Bresenham or more likely in this case due to anti-aliasing, [Wu's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm).

However, none of these support lines thicker than one pixel.

When you need lines with a different thickness than one you need to apply a whole lot more of math to it such as its angle, its tangents at the ends; it needs to be filled (like a polygon, one way or another using either scan line, or less likely "bucket" fill or replication of the lines with offsets as this produces gaps/holes in many cases) etc. If the lines are joined the angle of the joints needs to be calculated in relation to previous line's angle as well as type of join and so forth.

The whole process is a bit more complicated so it's to be expected that this will take more time than a one pixel thick line.

PS: `lineWidth` need only be set right before `stroke()` as this is the only time it's actually used.

**Added note:** although this is the case at the lowest level the browser does not necessary implement these algorithms *itself* as they may use sub-systems such as DirectX etc. but is observed through the browser's use of these.